# "An invalid handle was specified" on OpenCV VideoCapture creation

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I trying to get video from a webcam using OpenCV 2.4.5 and Visual C++ 2010, but when I try to initializate the VideoCapture

```
VideoCapture cap(1);
```

I get this error:
    0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.

The camera is connected and working. I tryied with 0 and -1 as parameters, with the same result. If I continue the excecution of the program, ignoring the error, the cap variable is null.
According to what I've read somwhere else, if I excecute the generated .exe, the program works OK. But obviously I need to work inside Visual to debug properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked this link? Please go through. There is an example code also. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: @2vision2 That's the code base I'm using. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I found a workaround: pressing the omit button when the exception raises. The execution of the program will continue with normality.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the cvSetCaptureProperty and also try to give the video input through the cvCaptureFromCAM, because cvCaptureFromCAM is specific api for camera.

Comment: I've just tried cvCaptureFromCAM but I'm getting the same error. I neither can try cvSetCaptureProperty because it must be applied to a capture object, and I cant initialize it. :(